# Why does browser send TLS session ID first time visit a website?

Tags: ssl

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22223519/5983841) of [SSL session tickets vs session ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939247/ssl-session-tickets-vs-session-ids).

> When the server sends the “Server Hello” message, it can include a session identifier. The client should store it and present it in the “Client Hello” message of the next session.

So my guess is that if I visit a website that I never visit before, there will be no `Session ID` in the `Client Hello` message.

But when I visit a new website that I randomly choose from Google (I am pretty sure that I never visit that website before) , I see a `Session ID` is sent in the `Client Hello` message. Why?

[image]

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/188495/what-is-the-session-id-parameter-indicate-in-client-hello-and-server-hello-messa

Comment: @Joe Thanks Joe, but that does not answer my question. My situation is **I never visit the website before, thus no previous handshake or session ID involved**, but **Why a session ID is contained in the `Client Hello` message sent by client/browser?**

Comment: @Rick: Are you really sure that you've never visited the site before?  It might have been included in some previous page even though you did not explicit visit it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes I am pretty sure. In the DMZ chatroom, I was suggested to to use command line connection in case of browser pre-fetch. I still saw session ID in client hello. You can easily perform a test with Wireshark. Check this chatroom link https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51051182#51051182

Comment: Moreover, I turned off WIFI connection on my cellphone and used 4G network,  again randomly chose a website I've never visited. Then I connected to that website on my PC (local network), still I saw the session ID.